# How to bind only certain elements in a list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list that contains many data frames, but I only want to bind a few of them together into a new data frame. Here's some mock data that resembles what I'm doing:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date_time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(date_time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
df3 <- data.frame(date_time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))

df.list <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)
```

I only want to bind together df1 and df2 from the list. In my actual data, I apply functions to the entire list of data frames, so I can't simply bind the original df1 and df2 data frames. Would it be possible to use rbind to extract df1 and df2 from the list and bind them into a new data frame, while still maintaining the list?

Using R version 3.5.1, Mac OS X 10.13.6

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df_bind <- rbind(df.list$df1, df.list$df2)
```

This gives you a dataframe:

```
 date_time var1 var2
1          1    a    1
2          2    b    1
3          3    c    0
4          4    d    0
5          5    e    1
6          1    a    1
7          2    b    1
8          3    c    0
9          4    d    0
10         5    e    1
```

Comment: This was simpler than I had made it out to be, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If we want to get more than one list element, `rbind` can be used with `do.call` after subsetting the `list` elements

```
do.call(rbind, df.list[1:2])
```